# localStorage добавление ключей

Tags: javascript, dom, localstorage

```
    let contacts = {
        name: name.value,
    };
    let emails = {
        email: email.value,
    };

    setNameToStorage(contacts);
    setEmailToStorage(emails);
});

function setNameToStorage(name) {
    let _name = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("names")) || [];
    _name.push(name);
    localStorage.setItem("names", JSON.stringify(_name));
}

function setEmailToStorage(email) {
    let _email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("emails")) || [];
    _email.push(email);
    localStorage.setItem("emails", JSON.stringify(_email));
}
```

Пытаюсь добавить в локал имена и мейлы, при нажатии на кнопку, считывая данные, но не получается, при этом если я добавляю только имена, коменчу 2ую функцию и убираю 2ой обьект, все добавляется нормально

Comment: Достаточно было открыть консоль и посмотреть ошибку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто

У вас АЧИПЯТКА. Вы пытаетесь сохранить несуществующую переменную email, вместо _email

```
function setEmailToStorage(email) {
    let _email = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("emails")) || [];
    _email.push(email);
    localStorage.setItem("emails", JSON.stringify(_email));
}
```

Старайтесь выбирать имена переменных попроще, что бы не запутаться и console.log() с отладчиком вам в помощь :)

Comment: исправил, не помогло(

Comment: А вы почистили localStorage после предыдущих экспериментов(**localStorage.removeItem('emails')**)? В предыдущие разы вы туда сохраняли объект и скорее всего скрипт сейчас падает на том, что достаются старые данные(Объект) и к объекту пытаетесь применить свойство push(), а оно доступно только для массивов.

Comment: разобрался, спасибо!